# How to trigger Tooltip on input after 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, tooltip

I'm currently using Angularjs (version 1.5.8) and I'm developing an application where a series of inputs are generated dynamically, and I want that when you focus an input and you take 5 seconds or more to start writing, appears a tooltip (the tooltip is the same for all inputs), currently I have a tooltip directive that supports trigger events ('click', 'mouseenter', 'focus').

I made a first version of what I want using the click trigger, but sometimes there are unwanted behaviors, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Use the `mouseenter` event (or `focus`) and set a timeout to add the `title` attribute to the input (or create an explicit tooltip component to appear). If the user has any `keypress` or just plain model input, then cancel the timeout ?

Comment: when i use $(#id).trigger('mouseenter') nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

```
let input = document.getElementById('input');
input.onfocus = function(){
  let a = 0;
  setTimeout(function(){alert('Please, write something');}, 5000);
};

/* Replaces the function alert('Please ...') with the function that manages your tooltip */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="input" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want the event to happen only if you haven't written anything in five seconds.

Answer (score 0):

`

$scope.focus = function() {

setTimeout(function(){ 
alert("test"); }, 5000);`

you write tooltip code ...inside of function.
you write custom directive called element.on("focus")